# Are legendary cards always gold?

Tags: hearthstone

I've recently open a new pack in Hearthstone and it contained a gold legendary card. I have the promo legendary for making a real-money purchase during beta, which also is gold, and I've seen a couple legendaries played against me, which I believe also were gold.
Yet various Hearthstone database sites show images for normal (silver) versions of legendary cards.

Are the legendary cards always gold? Was I *extremely* lucky, or just lucky?

Comment: What card did you get? Any chance of a screenshot?

Comment: @axrwkr I believe the exact card isn't really relevant to the question, but it was [Alexstrasza](http://hearthhead.com/card=581/alexstrasza)

Comment: The promo cards given away are always gold, but the normal version are available through crafting

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, not every legendary card is gold. The gold versions are just rarer versions of the original legendary. Each card in the game has a normal and a gold version.

I got [Jaraxxus](http://hearthstone.wikia.com/wiki/Lord_Jaraxxus) in a pack and he was normal. Click on Jaraxxus to see his wiki.
In this Wiki it shows both versions of the legendary.

Comment: That's the kind of confirmation I was counting on. I've also seen the images of normal versions of legendaries on various wiki-like sites, but since the game is in beta, and my limited experience presented me with, as I now know, quite improbable sample of only golden-bordered legendaries, I wasn't sure if the normal versions actually existed in the game. Thanks.

Comment: No problem, if you got any other questions you can just ask here.